# Are there any State Space Control C libraries?

Tags: control-systems, c, state-space

I'm searching for a C library which implements methods needed for state space control (e.g. state feedback controller and state observer equations).

Googling various terms only brought up a non-C (C# ?) library:

https://github.com/tomstewart89/StateSpaceControl

Therefore I was hoping to find existing projects which use C state space control algorithms or ready to use libraries with your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you understand state space control well enough to use it productively, you only need a matrix library, such as Eigen.